# Remote Play Movies/Music

Tags: ssh, files, gnome-terminal

I have a basic understanding of using SSH, as in that it allows you to access files on a remote server from a local client, to run on the remote server. 
However, what I am trying to achieve is a way to access the files on the server, to run on the client. I have an external HD connected to my server machine that is full of movies and music and it simply isn't practical to physically have the HD when I am out and about. How could I access/play these files ON THE CLIENT? Is there a way to do this without using a service such as UbuntuOne (due to limited storage)?

Comment: Absolutely valid case for using ssh ... BUT not very efficient regarding bandwidth use. You have to download the entire file to start reproducing it. A better alternative would be to install media streaming server software on your machine (Plex comes to mind). Much better use of bandwidth. Another alternative would be to buy a 16GB or 32GB flash drive (10 to 25Euro) and copy whatever you wish to carry with you in advance (this is what I do).

Comment: I will have to check out Plex, as that sounds like the best bet for what I am aiming for. Currently, I am going about it in the same method you suggest later; the downfall being that I don't have access to all of the files and I tend to be a bit indecisive at times, which is why I would like my entire library to be available.

Answer (score 0):

If client and server is Linux You can run: `sshfs <IP of server>:/ /mnt` - this will mount entire filesystem of server in client - look for your external HDD on a client in `/mnt/media/your_username_in_server/`
Otherwise try one of [this methods](https://serverfault.com/questions/120877/transfer-files-via-ssh#120881).

Comment: This would work, if the internal HD of my local machine was as large or larger than that of the external HD connected to my server, which is not the case.